# Photoshop Script - resize images in folder (dialog box)

Tags: javascript, batch-file, resize, photoshop, jsx

i would like to know if there is an easy way to write a simple script in Photoshop.

I would like it to pop a dialog box to let user select a folder. Then the scripts creates another folder ("web_ready") inside selected one and put resized images into it. I can handle the resizing part pretty easily (there is a lot of tutorials on the web) but i don't know how to write the part with dialog box pop-up. Can you help me? I am talking about *.jsx scripts.

Comment: welcome to SO, here you may find advice, help and support rather that free code it is not appropiate to just ask "please give me the scripts"; so you better tell us what you tried and what problems you found and we may help you. To begin, see app.OpenDialog().

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Folder select dialog:

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process");
```

Get the files from the folder:

```
var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles("*.JPG"); //Use whatever extension you want or no extension to select all files
```

Do something with the files:

```
for(var i=0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
    //do something..
}
```