# Photoshop - Auto align images into a grid

Tags: plugins, automation, photoshop

Is there a script/plugin/action available that will automatically align several images into a grid style layout e.g. wookmark ?

I am desperately in need of something to automate this, as a weekly project I have to arrange about 40 thumbnails into a PSD.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript...

You can define a selection using an array of coordinate points like so:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var w = thumbnailDoc.width; // width of thumbnail document
var h = thumbnailDoc.height; // height of thumbnail document

var sel = [ // Define a rectangle of coordinate points 
    [x, y], // moving clockwise from top-left corner of rectangle
    [x + w, y],
    [x + w, y + h],
    [x, y + h],
    [x, y] //back to start
];

var doc = app.documents.add(200, 200, 72) // create new document (width, height, resolution)

doc.selection.select(sel); // make a selection using the array of coordinates
doc.paste(true) // paste the contents of the clipboard
                // pass in the boolean 'true' to make it paste into the selection
```

So all you have to do is loop through all the pictures, resize them to thumbnails if you haven't already, copy to the clipboard, then paste into the selection on the working document. Increment your x,y coordinates as you go and you're strolling.

Comment: Erm, that looks awesome, but how do I use this in Photoshop exactly? :/

Comment: Sorry, I misread, thought you were writing your own script. Check out here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: Before I read the link, I saved the script into a .jsx and tried to run it, but it kicked off about "thumbnailDoc.width" being undefined. Obviously this needs to be fetched form the thumbnail image, how would you do that? I'll read the link now :)

Comment: Sorry, it's not a complete script, just the copy/paste portion. You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257646/photoshop-script-resize-images-in-folder-dialog-box/10304886#10304886 to load an entire folder of images (thumbnails) into an array. Then, within the loop, assign `thumbnailDoc = open(fileList[i]);`... `thumbnailDoc.selection.selectAll(); thumbnailDoc.selection.copy();` will copy the thumbnail to the clipboard.