# Resize batch images in PhotoShop

Tags: canvas, automation, photoshop, image-resizing

I am frequently presented with the task of resizing images (lots of them) to a square and then saving them with PhotoShop. For example, if an image is 400x200 then I would need to resize the canvas to be 400x400. Likewise, if an image is 321x850 then the canvas would be resized to 850x850 if, and if the image is 521x250 then the canvas would be resized to 521x521.

Is there a way in PhotoShop to automate this tedious task? I know about PhotoShop automate, which records your actions, but that's not what I want. I have no problem programming the solution if you could point me in the right direction. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance. This could save me hours and hours of tedious repetitive work.

Comment: I think you should use VSO Image Resizer, sometimes i have to make similar thing, you have to set the mode to center and that's all.

Comment: scripting with JS should be fine for me thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using javascript: You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304886/958490) to pick all the files in a chosen folder and loop through them. Within the loop you'll want to open each file like so:

```
var doc = open(fileList[i]);
```

then do a check of the length vs width:

```
if (doc.width !== doc.height) {             // if document is not already square...
    if (doc.width > doc.height) {               // if width is greater...
        doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)   // use this value for both sides...
    } else {                                      // else use height for both sides...
        doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)      // so you always get a square.
    }
}
```

save and close:

```
doc.save();
doc.close();
```

Depending on what you're looking for there is `doc.resizeImage()` as well.

[Adobe scripting guides](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Batch resize images in Mac OS X**

You can easily batch resize groups of images within Mac OS X by using the included Preview app, there is no need for any additional downloads or expensive photo editing applications, only Preview, which is free with your Mac! Here’s how to do it:

```
1. Select all the images you want resized and open them within Preview
2. From Preview, select the images that you want to batch resize from the drawer (Command+A will select them all)
3. Now, go to the menu labeled Tools, and then Adjust Size
4. Enter a value for what you want the new width and height to be
5. Next, navigate to the File menu and click Save All
6. All the images you selected are now resized!
```

This works in Preview that is included in virtually all versions of Mac OS X, happy batch resizing!

Answer (score 0):

Used this script it errors out.

```
if (doc.width !== doc.height) {             // if document is notalready square...
     if (doc.width > doc.height) {               // if width is greater...
         doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)   // use this value for both sides...
     else {                                      // else use height for both sides...
         doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)      // so you always get a square.
     } }
```

It says illegal use of else on line 4

Comment: You're closing your brackets wrongly… You should have a single curly bracket just before your else statement. I would push your last one down a line too and maintain your indentation / nesting - helps you spot when loops aren't quite right

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because there is a missing '}' at the end of line 3.
The if-term has to be close BEFORE the else-term is opened.

```
if (doc.width !== doc.height) {                // if document is notalready square...
 if (doc.width > doc.height) {                 // if width is greater...
     doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)}   // use this value for both sides...
 else {                                        // else use height for both sides...
     doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)} // so you always get a square.
 }
```