# Photoshop - Using an action/script to scale down and dump images in a separate folder

Tags: image, scale, photoshop, clipping, photoshop-script

My Java program is failing to correctly scale down the clipping paths on images.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a script or action for Photoshop that keeps the original but scales down the image (to a set height and width) and dumps them in a preset folder?

Help would be definitely appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

it is certainly possible.  Scripts will give you more flexibility then actions, and they can be done in javascript.  See any answer like this one for more info.  [Resize batch images in PhotoShop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538242/resize-batch-images-in-photoshop)