# Assigning a variable using a ruler measurement Photoshop CS6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Alright guys, I'm quite a newbie when it comes to programming however I have managed to get a simple script done to do part of the work.

I have 1,500 images of brake pads that need to be resized to a 1:1 scale so that the image is the same size on screen as it is in real life. I have worked out that the size of each image needs to be (real life width of the pad * 2.834)

My current script prompts the user for the width of the brake pad and assigns the size, in pixels, of the pad image however each pad is a different shape with a different sized border around the image [like in this example](http://i.imgur.com/YXC03.jpg).

What I need is for the user to be able to select from one side of the pad to the other which will return the current width, in pixels, of the pad. I will then be able to divide how big the pad needs to be by the current size of the pad to find a scale factor for the whole image.

Comment: Hi Corey, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, we don't use signatures here, so please don't be surprised or offended if/when yours is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better Solution:

You can pop a new window with the image using scriptUI and then attach an event listener to that image which you can't do to the document itself, unfortunately. Within the callback function add the X coord to the array, if the array length is greater than 2 hide the window and run the process function. This way, your first click sets the first point, second click sets the second point. And third click runs the processing function. If you want to get really fancy you could use right-click to reset the whole thing if you mess up but I'll leave that up to you.

```
#target photoshop

function processImage(image, partWidth) {
    // Your function to resize the image based on the part width
    alert(partWidth); // For testing purposes
}

// Save the current unit preferences (optional)
var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits
var startTypeUnits = app.preferences.typeUnits

// Set units to PIXELS
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS

var doc = app.activeDocument; // or the next file in your file array if doing multiple
var clicks = [];
var width = 0;

var w = new Window("dialog", "The Image");
var img = w.add("image", undefined, File(doc.fullName));
img.addEventListener("click", function(k) {
                                if (clicks.length < 2) {
                                    clicks.push(k.clientX);
                                }
                                else {
                                    // absolute value so it doesn't matter if 
                                    // we click right or left side first
                                    width = Math.abs(clicks[0] - clicks[1]); 
                                    w.hide;
                                    processImage(doc, width);
                                }
                            });

w.show();

// Reset to previous unit prefs (optional)
app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;
app.preferences.typeUnits = startTypeUnits;
```

All you need to do is loop through a bunch of images using something like this [Photoshop Script - resize images in folder (dialog box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257646/photoshop-script-resize-images-in-folder-dialog-box/10304886#10304886) and throw this code into the loop to do this as a batch.

(You may have a problem if the image is larger than the screen size and scaling the image down or adding scrollbars is very difficult and hacky with scriptUI, unfortunately)

Lame Solution:

One way to go about it is to have the user make a selection of the width of the part using the Rectangular Marquee Tool (the square selection box). Then you can access the dimensions of the selection. The selection bounds are stored in an array in the form of `[top-leftX, top-leftY, bottom-rightX, bottom-rightY]` To get the width of the selection you can subtract the first X value from the second.

Example snippet:

```
#target photoshop

var bounds = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds;
var selectionWidth = bounds[3] - bounds[0];

alert(selectionWidth);
```

The only caveat to this is the user has to make the selection BEFORE running the script.

There could be another way to do this using the scriptUI event listeners. The trouble is they have to be applied to a scriptUI object like a window or a pallate. You could try to make a large window with an opacity of 0 and add a click event to the window to capture the mouse coordinates. Honestly, this would be easier to do outside photoshop using java or C# or something.