# Photoshop Script for flattening TIFF

Tags: photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

I am using Photoshop CS5.5, is there a way to write a javascript that can

1. For each of TIFF image under a folder with many sub-folders
2. If the TIFF file has more then one layer
3. Then flatten the image and save as the original to a PSD?

Comment: What do you mean by *"save as the original"*?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about opening files on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257646/photoshop-script-resize-images-in-folder-dialog-box).

Flattening an image is simple:

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
docRef.flatten();
```

I don't know what you mean by "save as the original", but you can see the classes and options for saving documents [on this page](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/index_Classes%20for%20specifying%20options%20when%20saving%20documents.html). That's a quite useful site, by the way, it lists many other classes and their respective options.